# Trigger another workflow after confirmation task is approved

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I need to start another workflow if first WF confirmation task is approved. I could update field with value and do If Field = Value then send email but I can't do that because I will be using SP alert system and every time something gets approved the email will be send about modified item. Is it possible to trigger another workflow some how? For example trigger WF2 from WF1. Also I don't have option to use start a list workflow option. I am using SharePoint 2013, platform Sharepoint 2010 Workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by modifying a field. Create a new field in your form or update that field either using the workflow or by adding rules to directly change the forms value. For example if you have a status field and when a user first submits a form the stus field gets set to submitted which triggers the workflow. Now when the admin approves or rejects the form the status should change from submitted to approved/rejected causing the second workflow to get triggered or you can combine both actions into one workflow itself [image]

Over here I am using a single workflow to achieve multiple things . If your requirement if different you can create a new field and set that fields value to something else so that it will trigger the second workflow.
Hope this helped someone :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to call a SP2010 workflow from a SP2013 workflow, but a SP2010 workflow can't call another SP2010 workflow.